# Making entire cell clickable

Tags: php, html

I have a `div` container with a title and content as shown in the picture.

[image]

Here is the markup:

```
$output .= '<h1 class="list_title">';
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink () . '">'.the_title ('','',false) . '</a>';                  
$output .= '</h1>';

$output .= '<div class="list_content">';
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink () . '">';
        $output .= wp_trim_words ($post->post_content, $content_length );
    $output .= '</a>';
$output .= '</div>';
```

In these two components, I added `get_permalink` so that users can click either the title or the content to go to the post link.

However, I am trying to make it so that user can click anywhere in the cell (such as the empty space as `B` to go to the link.

Can anyone tell me how I can make the whole cell clickable instead just the title or content?

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in `<a>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is wrap the whole `<div>` in an `<a>` tag;

```
$output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink () . '">'.the_title ('','',false) . '</a>';  
$output .= '<h1 class="list_title">';

$output .= '<div class="list_content">';
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink () . '">';
        $output .= wp_trim_words ($post->post_content, $content_length );
$output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</a>';
```

I removed the `<h22>` tag, it was empty.

Comment: `<h22>` no doubt this is his mistake but you don't have to remove it, you have to replace that with `</h1>`, it's not the empty tag, he is concatenating the entire string hence that's the closing tag he opened on first line

Comment: Thanks guys! And it was supposed to be `</h1>` and just wrote it wrong. Thanks Anyway =) Got it working by wrapping `div` by `a`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put div inside `<a>` and maybe add `display: block` to `<a>`:

```
$output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink () . '">';
    $output .= '<div class="list_content">';
        $output .= wp_trim_words ($post->post_content, $content_length );
    $output .= '</div>';
$output .= '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of your tags. The `<div>` should be inside the `<a>`.

```js
$output. = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">';
  $output. = '<div class="list_content">';
    $output. = wp_trim_words($post - > post_content, $content_length);
  $output. = '</a>';
$output. = '</div>';
```

That means that the whole div is a *link*.